# Как в Godot сделать чтобы только Ui элементы (Например кнопка) реагировали на клик?

Tags: c#, godot

Дело в том у меня перемещение сделано по клику мышки если жму на кнопку, то получается реагирует и кнопка и перемещение. Клик с кнопки снимаю так:

```
public class ButtonSignalSender : Button
{

public override void _GuiInput(InputEvent @event)
    {
        if (@event is InputEventMouseButton mouseEvent && mouseEvent.ButtonIndex == (int)ButtonList.Left && mouseEvent.Pressed)
        {
            GD.Print("CLICK CLUCK");
            // обработка события клика на кнопке здесь
        //     if (@event is InputEventWithModifiers)
        // {
        //     InputEventWithModifiers inputEventWithModifiers = (InputEventWithModifiers)@event;
        //     inputEventWithModifiers.SetHandled();
        // }
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал по совету GPT решить проблему кодом который сейчас закомментирован, но выводит ошибку в самом редакторе:

```
"InputEventWithModifiers" не содержит определения "SetHandled", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "SetHandled", принимающий тип "InputEventWithModifiers" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)
```